# How should I change the resource dictionary in WinRT project?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I am looking to change the default resource dictionaries in the WinRT project. Which file should I touch to change the default colours for the system resources in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

***generic.xaml*** is what you're looking for.

It's located at "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\WinRT\Xaml\Design\generic.xaml**" by default.

Do not edit this file though. You can always override the styles & templates inside this file in your App.xaml. Just override the default resources with the same x:Key convention.